# Order Number in Sharepoint. Integer?

Tags: sharepoint, numbers, integer, fieldtype

I add a list column that should be used as a order column programaticly. As a field type I would use SPFieldType.Integer.

Now I just wonder why this field type cannot be chosen from the user. Are there any good reasons, why Number can be selected, but Integer cannot from within the lists properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean but a common misstake in SharePoint development is made by handling number fields as integers when they actually are Double values.

Comment: I just wonder why Integer cannot be chosen when adding or modifying a List field directly from ViewLsts. Is there any reason why MS decided to disallow this field type? Is it inperformant in Sharepoint? etc.

Comment: I assume the underlying object layer that runs SharePoint needs any standardization it can get.

Answer (score 2):

You can create integer field either through the UI (new field : number and set **Number of decimal places to 0** which is not native)
or through CAML

eg :

```
   <Field
    ID="{5CCF58EA-0F3B-4D49-9797-A4BEF557FB15}"
    Name="Banner_BodyWidth"
    DisplayName="Banner Body Width"
    Type="Number"
    Decimals="0"
    Min="0"
    Required="FALSE">
    <Default>300</Default>
</Field>
```

Or the other side, don't forget that you have a built-in order field in all content type that you can safely use for that purpose and will give you an UI that you won't have to develop if you go to **http(s)://your-site-collection-url/_layouts/reorder.aspx?List={guid-of-the-targeted-list}**

Hope it helped.